# Matrix With Positive Trace can be Written as a PSD matrix plus a Commutator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Then $Tr(A) \ge 0$ if and only if $A = P + C$, where $P \ge 0$ and $Tr(C) =0$.

The one direction is trivial. Suppose that $Tr(A) \ge 0$ and note that

$A = \frac{A+A^*}{2} + i \frac{A-A^*}{2i}$

Then

$0 \le Tr(A) = Tr(\frac{A+A^*}{2}) + i Tr(\frac{A-A^*}{2i})$

Since $\frac{A+A^*}{2}$ and $\frac{A-A^*}{2i}$ are both hermitian, the only way $Tr(A)$ will be some real number is if $Tr(\frac{A-A^*}{2i}) = 0$. Hence, $Tr(\frac{A+A^*}{2}) \ge 0$.

Now I am trying to show that $\frac{A+A^*}{2}$ can be split into a PSD matrix and trace-zero diagonal, but I am having some trouble. The problem is reduced to the following:

> Suppose that $H^*=H$ and $Tr(H) \ge 0$. Can $H$ be written as a PSD matrix plus a trace-zero diagonal?

Let $D(H)$ denote the diagonal of $H$. Here is what I tried:

$H = (H + D(H) - Tr(H)I) + (Tr(H)I - D(H))$

Clearly $Tr(H)I - D(H)$ will be trace-zero diagonal, but I don't think the other piece is PSD...I could use some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, we can make things way easier: take
$P = \frac {Tr(A)}{n} I$,
where $I$ denotes the identity matrix.

Comment: Hmm...Would you mind expanding on this a little?

Comment: What else is there to say? Where are you getting stuck?  Do you see that $P$ is positive definite?  That $A - P$ has trace zero?